# Why do I need to cast `as NonNullable<T>` after checking for null and undefined?

Tags: typescript

```
// This is an implementation of https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5b%27t%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d
const choose = <T, U>(
  collection: T[],
  selector: (elem: T) => U
): NonNullable<U>[] => {
  const result: NonNullable<U>[] = [];
  for (const element of collection) {
    const value = selector(element);
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      // result.push(value); TypeScript complains that U is not convertible to NonNullable<U>
      result.push(value as NonNullable<U>); // this works
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Why do I need the cast there and is there a way to type this so I don't need to? TypeScript is usually able to tell something cannot be null or undefined inside an if statement that checks for those cases.

Comment: That seems to be a limitation of the non-nullable type. There exists a non-null assertion operator that you could also use (as described in https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html) which would result in
`result.push(value!)`

Comment: This could depend upon your tsconfig.json, but simply removing the inline typedef for `result` works. `const result = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to resolve.  You could simply remove the inline typedef for `result`

```js
const choose = <T, U>(
  collection: T[],
  selector: (elem: T) => U
): NonNullable<U>[] => {
  const result = [];
  for (const element of collection) {
    const value = selector(element);
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      result.push(value); // this works
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

Given that you're porting this from F# a better solution for you may be to include strict null checks in your tsconfig.json so that you don't have to explicitly specify `NonNullable` in the first place though.

```js
//with "strictNullChecks": true in your tsconfig.json
const choose = <T, U>(
  collection: T[],
  selector: (elem: T) => U
): U[] => {
  const result = [];
  for (const element of collection) {
    const value = selector(element);
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
       result.push(value);
       //result.push(undefined);  //can't do this and also return result
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

If you pushed `undefined` to `result` and tried to return `result`, the compiler would complain that the result type of the function would have to be `U | undefined`

You could also embrace the concept of immutability with something like this.

```js
const choose = <T, U>(collection: T[], selector: (elem: T) => U): U[] =>
  collection.reduce((p, c) => {
    const value = selector(c);
    return value ? [...p, value] : p;
  }, []);
```

Either way my suggestion would be to turn on strictNullChecks if you're interested in dealing with the effect of undefined (Maybe, Option, whatever you'd like to call it)

**Per comments**

> The selector function is expected to return null or undefined.

In that case I'd suggest calling that out in the function signature

```js
const choose = <T, U>(collection: T[], selector: (elem: T) => U | undefined): U[] => {
  const result = [];
  for (const element of collection) {
    const value = selector(element);
    if (value) result.push(value);
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that TypeScript could infer `U` to be, e.g. `number | null`. I want this function to return an array of things that are not null or undefined.

Comment: Also, the first approach does not work for me. TypeScript complains that `U[]` is not convertible to `NonNullable<U>[]`.

Comment: `U` could only be `number | null` if the `selector` function you pass to `choose` allows it.  *and strict null checks are on

Comment: Right, but that is the expected usage. The selector function is expected to return `null` or `undefined` sometimes; and this function chooses the non-null results and returns only those.

Comment: Ah, your last example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, great to hear!